Fréchet but not strongly
I can come up with an example of a function which is Fréchet differentiable in $0$, while not being strongly differentiable. It is $x^2\mathbf{1}_{\mathbb{Q}}$, which is pretty straightforward. Well, does anyone know an example of a function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ that is Fréchet differentiable everywhere and not strongly differentiated in $0$?
I also include definitions of both terms:
Let $X, Y$ be normed spaces.
We say that $f: U \to Y$, $U \subseteq X$ is Fréchet differentiated at $x_0$ if there exists a linear and continuous operator $A\in L(X, Y)$, such that
$$f(x_0 + h) = f(x_0) + Ah + o(\vert\vert h \vert \vert)_{h\to 0}.$$ Then $A$ is called its Fréchet derivative.
We say that $f$ has is strongly differentiable at $x_0$ if there exists $A \in L(X, Y)$ such that:
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{c}\forall \varepsilon > 0 \; \exists \delta > 0 \; \forall x_1, x_2: \\ {\vert\vert} x_1 - x_0{\vert\vert} < \delta,{\vert\vert} x_2 - x_0{\vert\vert} < \delta \implies {\vert\vert} f(x_1) - f(x_2) - A(x_1 - x_2){\vert\vert}_{Y} < \varepsilon {\vert \vert} x_1 - x_2{\vert\vert}_X .
\end{array}
\end{equation}

It may be a good idea to include both definitions involving differentiability in your question.

It’s Fréchet

If I remember correctly, if $f$ is everywhere differentiable, then strong differentiability is equivalent to continuity of the derivative.

A standard example is $f(x)=\begin{cases}x^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right),&x\neq 0\\ 0,&x=0\end{cases}$, this is Fréchet différentiable éverywhere, but is not strongly differentiable at $0$.
Note that $\liminf_{x \to 0} f'(x) = -1$, $\limsup_{x \to 0} f'(x) = +1$. I n particular, no $A$ exists that can satisfy the definition above.
To elaborate the previous statement, note that if $f$ was strongly differentiable at $0$ then there would be some $A$ such that
$\lim_{\delta \downarrow 0} \sup_{x_1,x_2 \in B(0,\delta)\setminus \{0\}} |{f(x_1)-f(x_2) \over x_1-x_2} -A| = 0$.
Suppose $f'(x_k) \to 1$ for some sequence $x_k \to 0$. Then there is some sequence $y_k \to 0$, with $y_k \neq x_k$ such that $\lim_k{f(y_k)-f(x_k) \over y_k -x_k} = 1$ and so we must have $A=1$.
Repeating with a subsequence $f(x_k') \to -1$ shows that $A=-1$, a contradiction.

How does the difference of limits imply that there is no strong differentiability?

It is a matter of applying the definitions, I have elaborated above.
